# notepad++ delete duplicate and original lines to keep unique lines

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with many duplicate lines and I am looking for a way to delete this duplicate and the original lines in notepad++, so that I can keep just the unique lines.

Or a way to mark all the unique lines. Or to mark all duplicates and originals to remove them manually.

The way is not that important, but at the result, I just need the unique lines.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your file is something like this

[image]

Then select the text and use `TextFX Tools` --> `Sort lines case insensitive (at column)`. Make sure that you have `Sort outputs only UNIQUE (at columns) line` selected.

[image]

Comment: This is to delete duplicate lines. I need to delete the duplicate and the original to keep just the unique lines. In this sample is the only line I need "or a way to mark all the uniques lines".

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post and that you were looking for a notepad++ solution, but I came across this while searching for a solution for the same issue myself.

I ended up just using cygwin -- which I already had installed at the time-- and gnu tools.

```
uniq -u <sorted.file>
```

This only outputs the unique lines in the `sorted.file` file. Example:

```
# cat test.file
this is a dup line
this is also a dup line
this is a dup line
this is unique line 4
this is yet another dup
this is a dup line
this is also a dup line
this is unique line 1
this is unique line 3
this is also a dup line
this is yet another dup
this is unique line 2
```

Since the file is not sorted, I do so first:

```
# sort test.file | uniq -u
this is unique line 1
this is unique line 2
this is unique line 3
this is unique line 4
```