# Find and KEEP all duplicate lines in Notepad++ (delete all unique lines)

Tags: list, sorting, text, duplicates, notepad++

I am aiming to **identify and keep DUPLICATE, TRIPLICATE, etc.** lines, i.e., all lines that **occur more than once** in Notepad++? In other words, how can I delete all unique lines only?
For example:

```
1
2
3
4
4
4
5
6
7
8 
9
abc
abd
abd
abe
```

List of duplicates:

```
4
4
4
abd
abd
```

There are many solutions to **eliminate** duplicates (e.g., TextFX; [notepad++ delete duplicate and original lines to keep unique lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148)), I can not find options to **keep** them.

---

UPDATE 2: [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) This question is not less "broad" (in fact, one can hardly be more specific) or less researched than other Notepad++ questions, including the one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) cited (wrongly) by [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) et al. as the same question.

UPDATE:
[@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh), [@B. Desai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7450125/b-desai), [@Paolo Forgia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685157/paolo-forgia), [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449), [@Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth)
**This questions is different from:**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines)
beacuse Q [29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) is **(i)** neither asking how to identify and keep only the lines of multiple occurrence, **(ii)** neither there is a solution provided in the answers for that. Q [29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) asks "...I just need the unique lines."

Comment: You should write a script in your favorite scriptig language.

Comment: @B. Desai - The question you are pointing to is **neither asking to identify and KEEP DUPLICATES, neither there is an answer** of doing that. [stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines).  So: "This question already has an answer here:
notepad++ delete duplicate and original lines to keep unique lines " is **incorrect**.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - As Toto correctly says: **"They want just the opposite, keep the duplicate lines"**. So you marking this as an already answered question is incorrect. I updated my question, so it will be even more clear that to KEEP DUPLICATES.

Comment: @Paolo Forgia - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) The question here is **"...can keep just the unique lines"**.  I need to do the exact opposite, and there is no answer for that.

Comment: [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) If you misunderstood the question, then you should remove your suggestion to block it: your reasoning "This question already has an answer** is **incorrect and misleading for stackoverflow**, But now, you attacking its broadness: Well, it is **definitely** not broader or less researched in any respect than the **very** question you point to and  you (wrongly) allege I am "duplicating". I suggest you do the correct thing and withdraw your suggestion to block my question, as there is **no answer** posted for it.

Comment: [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) If you admit that that my questions was wrongly marked as duplicate by you, then what you mean "**also too broad**"? There is **no** "also", irrespective if broad or not, because your "duplicate" assertion was **wrong and void**.

Comment: [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) Could you please specify **factually**, how is my question more "broad" than [the one you quoating as a "legitimate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines)?