# Find and KEEP all DUPLICATE lines (instead of unique lines) in a text file

Tags: list, sorting, text, duplicates, notepad++

I am aiming to **identify and keep DUPLICATE, TRIPLICATE, etc.** lines, i.e., all lines that **occur more than once** in Notepad++? In other words, how can I delete all unique lines only?

For example, here are seven (7) separate lists and the desired true duplicate lines of each lists (shown as 7 columns, regard each column as an individual list or file!).  (The lists here are shown side by side **only to save space**, in real life, each of the 7 lists occurs alone and independently from the others and are separate files!)

```
list1  list2  list3  list4  list5  list6  list7
1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2      1      1      1      1      1      1
3      2      2      2      2      2      2
4      3      3      3      3      3      3
4      4      4      4      4      4      4
4      4      4      4      4      4      4
5      4      4      4      4      4      4
6      5      5      5      5      5      5
7      5      5      5      5      5      5
8      6      6      6      6      6      6
9      6      6      6      6      6      6
abc    7      7      7      7      7      7
abd    8      8      8      8      8      8
abd    9      9      9      9      9      9
abe           <CR>   9      9      9      9
                            <CR>   99     99
                                          <CR>

[Lines of multiple occurence of above lists:]         
4      4      4      4      4      4      4
4      4      4      4      4      4      4
4      4      4      4      4      4      4
abd    5      5      5      5      5      5
abd    5      5      5      5      5      5
       6      6      6      6      6      6
       6      6      6      6      6      6
                     9      9      9      9
                     9      9      9      9
```

There are many solutions to **eliminate** duplicates (e.g., TextFX; [notepad++ delete duplicate and original lines to keep unique lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148)), I can not find solutions to **keep** duplicates only.

`((.*)\R(\2\R)+)*\K.+\R`
@Lars Fischer: This script works nearly OK, except the last entry of the (presorted) list needs to be unique line followed by a `<CR>` empty line. One (suboptimal) workaround is to insert an artificial (helper) unique line (e.g., zzz) followed by an empty line `<CR>` as the last two lines.

(END OF QUESTION)

---

UPDATE 3: This question is reposted per stackoverflow "[ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699485/find-and-keep-all-duplicate-lines-in-notepad-delete-all-unique-lines)" instruction. ([@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh), [@B. Desai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7450125/b-desai), [@Paolo Forgia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685157/paolo-forgia), [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449), [@Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth) draw the incorrect conclusion that this question is a duplicate of [notepad++ delete duplicate and original lines to keep unique lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines). This question is definitely not a duplicate of the one [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) et al quotes. [image: History.]

UPDATE 2: [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) This question is not less "broad" (in fact, one can hardly be more specific) or less researched than other Notepad++ questions, including the one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) cited (wrongly) by [@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh) et al. as the same question.

UPDATE:
[@AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh), [@B. Desai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7450125/b-desai), [@Paolo Forgia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685157/paolo-forgia), [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449), [@Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth)
**This questions is different from:**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines)
beacuse Q [29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) is **(i)** neither asking how to identify and keep only the lines of multiple occurrence, **(ii)** neither there is a solution provided in the answers for that. Q [29303148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303148/notepad-delete-duplicate-and-original-lines-to-keep-unique-lines) asks "...I just need the unique lines."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a solution based on regular Expressions and *bookmarks*, it works for a **sorted** file (i.e. each duplicated line is followed by its duplicates):

- Open the Mark Dialog (Search -> Mark ....)
- click **Clear all Marks** on the right
- check **Bookmark line**
- check **Wrap aound**
- **Find What:** `((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*\K.*`
- Check **regular expression** and uncheck `. matches newline`
- **Mark All**
- Click **Close**
- Search -> Bookmark -> Remove Bookmarked Lines

**Explanation**

The regular expression is made up of three parts:

- `((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*` : this is an optional block of duplicates consisting of one ore more line blocks

  - the outher `( ... )*` matches zero or more such blocks of duplicated lines (if in your example the three 4 would be followed by two 5 we will need a concept of *sequences of duplicate blocks*)
  - `(.*)\R(\2\R?)+`: `\2` references the content of `(.*)`: this are all duplicates of one line
  - the second `\R` is an optional ( due to the `?`) linebreak. Thus it is possible to match a duplicate in the last line of the file if that line does not end with a linebreak

  If there is a block of duplicated lines after the cursor position from which you start, this will match it.
- now `\K` discards what we have matched so far (the duplicates) and "puts the cursor" before the first unique line
- `.*` matches the next (unique) line and bookmarks it

Using **Mark All** we bookmark all such unique lines, so that we can remove them using the Entry from the Search -> Bookmark menu.

Comment: NIce one. But don't forget to uncheck `. matches newline`

Comment: @Toto Thanks, I have inlcuded your hint.

Comment: `((.*)\R(\2\R)+)*\K.+\R` **It will NOT work if:** the last 2 or more lines of the **sorted** list contains duplicates. One (suboptimal) workaround is to insert an artificial (helper) **unique** line (e.g., `zzz`) followed by an empty line (`carriage return`) as the last two lines.

Comment: `((.*)\R(\2\R)+)*\K.+\R` You need an empty line ( `carriage return`) as last line manually inserted even if the **sorted** list ends with a **unique** line.  Otherwise it will keep the last unique line among the valid duplicate list. (Probably has to do with the line ending character recognition by the regex?)

Comment: Lists that do not work or work with the script (note the _ending_ of lists): **no good:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9`
**OK:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,<CR>`
**no good:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9`
**no good:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,<CR>`
**no good:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,99`
**OK:** `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,99,<CR>`
**Note:** comma (`,`) means a new line;`99` is a manually inserted helper unique line.

Comment: @user3026965 These list are not **literal** duplicates of each other: they differ in their characters (trailing comma). If you need logic, like *strip of characters* that are considered unimportant or add characters on the fly: you need to 1. define your **exact requirements** :)  and 2. write a program for your requirements.

Comment: @user3026965 `\R` *is* the linebreak. It is part of the match, so your last line needs to end with a linebreak.

Comment: @user3026965 You might want to try the regular expression `((.+)[, ]*\R(\2[, ]*\R)+)*\K.*\R` .  It might or might not work for your requirements that trailing spaces or comma are not considered part of a *duplicated line*.

Comment: @user3026965 the **no good/OK** sample lists (4th comment upward) are written as a single line because of the _prohibition_ to use `<CR>` in comments. as indicated, regard each comma `,` as a line break (`\R`), so those are lists with **10+ lines** each. (e.g., `0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9` is same as `0\R1\R2\R3\R4\R4\R4v5\R5\R6\R6\R7\R8\R9`).  Therefore, `4,5,6` and sometimes `9` are **literal duplicates of each other**.

Comment: @user3026965 Thanks for your explanation. You might want to try the regular expression `((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*\K.*`.  
It drops the need for the last linebreak in the last line and it works for the no good cases from your third comment. It should especially work for duplicates at the end of the list.

Comment: @Lars Fischer: `((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*\K.*` This seems to work, thank you very much! I suggest  to update your orig. response.

Comment: I had a similiar usecase, but with text/translations. This solution gave me partial matches for `OK` and `OK, thanks`, which are 'fake' duplicates. The solution for me was to make the second line-break non-optional. Maybe this helps some other users? Try `((.*)\R(\2\R)+)*\K.*` instead.