# Keep all lines of a list with identical beginning (Notepad++)

Tags: list, sorting, duplicates, notepad++

From a list, how to **keep all occurrences** of those lines only whose "first part or beginning" (defined from the beginning of the line to the `^` character) is present in other lines? (The pattern of lines in the list: **beginning-of-line**`^`rest_of_line_012345)

The type of characters, length, etc. after the `^` is irrelevant (but needs to be kept). Every line has only one (1) `^` character. The "beginning" string that determines identity must be present in the same (analogous) position in other lines (i.e., from the beginning of the line to `^`, and must be **exact match**). (Lines contain characters that trouble regex, such as `\/()*.`, so these need to be summarily escaped.)

**For example:** Original list:

```
abc^123
0xyz^xxx
aaa-123^123
aaa-12^0xyz
0xyz^098
00xyz^098
0xyz^x111xx
```

Keep all occurrences of lines with identical first part:

```
0xyz^xxx
0xyz^098
0xyz^x111xx
```

This elegant script by [@Lars Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727299/find-and-keep-all-duplicate-lines-instead-of-unique-lines-in-a-text-file)    `((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*\K.*` (after pre-sorting) keeps all occurrences of duplicate lines, but it considers the entire line (*it was designed to do so*).

In this Q, I am looking for a solution that considers only the "beginning" of the line to see if it occurs more than once, and if yes, then keep the entire line. Any guidance?

Comment: In your question there is only one pattern. Is it also asking if multiple patterns are present ? Please clarify with more sample data.

Comment: I wonder why pushing this to edge using regex-only approach if this can be done using [tag:awk], [tag:perl] or [tag:python] in less challenging way?

Comment: Re **"pattern"**. In my case, there is always one (1) single unique character (`^`) per line that serves as a delimiter for the beginning and rest of line. Re **"regex"** approach: It would be the easiest as I am working with Notepad++ a lot. A perl script would be a solution that I can also live with.

Answer (score 0):

Note: in this solution the characters # and % are used based on the assumption that these characters do not show up ANYWHERE in the file to begin with. If that's not the case for you, just use different patterns that you know don't show up anywhere in the file, such as ##### and %%%%%.

Start by sorting the file Lexicographically with Notepad++ by going to Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending

Do a regex Find-and-Replace (UNcheck the box for ". matches newline"):

Find what:

```
^(.*?)\^[^\r\n]+[\r\n]+(\1\^.*?[\r\n]+)*\1\^.*?$
```

Replace with:

```
#$&%
```

Now do another regex Find-and-Replace (CHECK the box for ". matches newline"):

Find what:

```
%.*?#
```

Replace with:

```
\r\n
```

Finally, do one last regex Find-and-Replace (CHECK the box for ". matches newline"):

Find what:

```
^.*?#|%.*
```

Replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You said in comments that a perl script is OK for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my %values;
my $file = 'path/to/file';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file': $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    # get the prefix value
    my ($prefix) = split('\^', $_);
    # push in array the whole line in hash with the prefix as key
    push @{$values{$prefix}}, $_;
}
foreach (keys %values) {
    # skip the prefix tat have only one line
    next if scalar @{$values{$_}} == 1;
    local $" = "\n";
    say "@{$values{$_}}";
}
```

**Output:**

```
0xyz^xxx
0xyz^098
0xyz^x111xx
```